# LINQ GroupBy Source = A Destination = B or Source = B and Destination = A

Tags: c#, linq

How to group having something like this:

```
Obj1 { Source = A, Destination = B }
Obj2 { Source = B, Destination = A }
```

I'm having trouble finding how to group those.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well, how do you *want* them to be grouped? Together? Because they are for an A/B pair?

Comment: Could you provide an *example*? Initial data and desired outcome?

Comment: Obj1
Source = 192.168.1.2
Destination = 192.168.1.1
Obj2
Source = 192.168.1.1
Destination = 192.168.1.2
I need to group them in that way
Key { Source = 192.168.1.1 ||  Source =192.168.1.2, 
Destination = 192.168.1.1 || Destination = 192.168.1.2 }
[0] = Obj1
[1] = Obj2

Comment: I've solved using that way but it looks odd:
sqlObjects..GroupBy(obj =>  String.Join(",", new List<string>() { obj.Destination.ToString(), obj.Source.ToString() }.OrderBy(s => s)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your objects contain the **string** properties **Source** and **Destination**, you could add a property or method which returns their values ordered in an alphabetical manner. That way, opposite values can be categorized as equal.

```
public class Obj
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    public string Key => string.Compare(Source, Destination) > 0 ? 
                              Source + "," + Destination : Destination + "," + Source;
 }
```

Then you can group them the following way:

```
 var groupedObjects = objects.GroupBy(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks. it looks a bit better.